Understanding sync_to_async method in Django?
I have never worked with asyncio and/or asynchronous methods with django and am having a little difficulty understanding.
I am trying to convert a synchronous utility function (create_email_record) into an asynchronous function inside of a form method.
I will minimize some code for better understanding. My form method (begin_processing) has a good amount of logic inside.
def create_email_record(submission):
    print("-----CREATE EMAIL RECORD-------")
    creation = EmailRecord.objects.create()


class Form(forms.Form):

    comments = forms.TextArea()

    def begin_processing():
        submission = Submission.objects.get(id=1)
        print("----------BEGIN ASYNC--------")
        create_email_notification = sync_to_async(create_email_record)(submission)
        asyncio.run(create_email_notification)
        print("----------END ASYNC----------")

When I print this to my terminal I would think to expect:
("----------BEGIN ASYNC--------")
("----------END ASYNC----------")
("-----CREATE EMAIL RECORD-------")
What I receive is:
("----------BEGIN ASYNC--------")
("-----CREATE EMAIL RECORD-------")
("----------END ASYNC----------")
My Object gets created, and seems to work, but I don't believe that my converted sync_to_async function is being converted/called correctly.
Maybe I am having some trouble understanding, but what I want to do is call an asynchronous function from a synchronous function/method. I have read a lot on other posts, and online resources, but none seem to fit what I am looking to do. I have not seen this done inside of a form method.

If you put the thread to sleep for a while from within create_email_record(), then it will do exactly what you want. Running the coroutine returned by sync_to_async() using asyncio.run() will execute it in a single, shared thread, but this will not be the main thread. The tendency that it will log in that exact manner it does is very high. If you need more clarification, I’ll write an answer when I get off work.

I am looking into this now. Is there a way to put the function asleep with the asyncio library, or would I need to include the Thread library, and combine asyncio with threading? Thanks for the help!

asyncio.run is never the thing to call inside a running program, as part of a repeated process. Rather - it is the thing to be called to "jump start" the async part of a program: it creates an asyncio loop, and is usually done once per process only.
